# Arduino addition assignment

Tags: c++, arduino

I do some programming using Arduino, but I have a problem. In the `loop()` function I want to add a value to a variable, `pwm`, each time the `loop()` function is executed. I obtain that value from some function I wrote and add it to `pwm` with the command `pwm += result`, but it does not work. If I print `pwm`, I always get zero. Even though printing `result` gives me some non-zero value. The whole code is:

```
float pwm = 0;
float result = 0;

void loop(){

    ....

    errV = w - cm;
    errDtV = errOldV - errV;

    result = flc->cog(errV, errDtV);

    Serial.print("RESULT: ");
    Serial.println(result);

    pwm += result;
    Serial.println(pwm);
}
```

And the output is like this:

```
RESULT: 31.98
0.00
```

What might be wrong?

EDIT: Here is the whole sketch

```
#include "FSet.h"
#include "FRule.h"
#include "Flc.h"
#include <NewPing.h>
#include "MotorControl.h"

MotorControl* m;
Flc* flc;
FRule* rule1,*rule2,*rule3,*rule4,*rule5,*rule6,*rule7,*rule8,*rule9;

NewPing sonar1(32,33,200);

static int dirA = 9;
static int pwmA = 8;

// Setup the FSets
FSet errZ(0,5,0);
FSet errMP(-15,15,0);
FSet errLP(-30,15,-1);

FSet errDtLN(-4,2,-1);
FSet errDtMN(-2,2,0);
FSet errDtZ(0,2,0);
FSet errDtMP(2,2,0);
FSet errDtLP(4,2,1);

FSet cntLN(-40,20,0);
FSet cntMN(-20,20,0);
FSet cntZ(0,20,0);
FSet cntMP(20,20,0);
FSet cntLP(40,20,0);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(4800); 
  pinMode(dirA,INPUT);

  //Creating FRules for test    
  rule1 = new FRule(&errZ,&errDtMP,&cntMN);
  rule2 = new FRule(&errZ,&errDtZ,&cntZ);
  rule3 = new FRule(&errZ,&errDtMN,&cntMP);
  rule4 = new FRule(&errMP,&errDtLP,&cntMN);
  rule5 = new FRule(&errMP,&errDtMN,&cntMP);
  rule6 = new FRule(&errLP,&errDtMP,&cntMP);
  rule7 = new FRule(&errLP,&errDtZ,&cntLP);  
  rule8 = new FRule(&errLP,&errDtMN,&cntLP);  
  rule9 = new FRule(&errLP,&errDtLN,&cntLP);  

  flc = new Flc(9);
  flc->addRule(rule1);
  flc->addRule(rule2);
  flc->addRule(rule3);
  flc->addRule(rule4);
  flc->addRule(rule5);
  flc->addRule(rule6);
  flc->addRule(rule7); 
  flc->addRule(rule8);
  flc->addRule(rule9); 

}

int errV = 0;
int errOldV = 0;
int errDtV = 0;
int w = 30;
unsigned int uS;
unsigned int cm;

float pwm1 = 0;
float result = 0;

void loop(){   
  uS = sonar1.ping();
  cm = (uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM);

  errV = w - cm;
  errDtV = errOldV - errV;    

  result = flc->cog(errV,errDtV);

  Serial.print("RESULT: ");
  Serial.println(result);

  pwm1 = pwm1 + result;  

  Serial.println(pwm1);
  analogWrite(pwmA,pwm1);

  errOldV = errV;

}
```

FLC class header file:
    #ifndef FLC_H
    #define FLC_H
    #include "Arduino.h"
    #include "FRule.h"

```
class Flc {
    public:
        Flc(int size);
        ~Flc();
        int addRule(FRule* rule);
        int mom(float x1,float x2);
        float cog(float x1,float x2);

        FRule** rules;

    private:
        int last;
        int size;
        float h;
        float numerator = 0;
        float denominator = 0;
        float result = 0;

};

#endif
```

FLC class source:
        #include "Arduino.h"
    #include "Flc.h"

```
Flc::Flc(int size){
    this->rules = (FRule**) malloc(sizeof(FRule*) * size);

    this->size = size;
    last = -1;
}

Flc::~Flc(){
    free(rules);
}

int Flc::addRule(FRule* rule){
    this->rules[++last] = rule;
    return last;
}

int Flc::mom(float x1,float x2){
    return 0.0;a
}

float Flc::cog(float x1, float x2){

    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++){

        h = rules[i]->dof(x1,x2);
        float area = rules[i]->widthOfCon() * ( h - h*h/2);

        numerator += rules[i]->cntrOfCon() * area;
        denominator += area;

    }

    result = numerator / denominator;

    return result;


}
```

Comment: Please post actual code that demonstrates the issue. The code snippit you post above literally can not do what you claim.

Comment: It is the actual code, I just ommitted the part, where I get values from sensors.

Comment: have you tried using `pwm = result + pwm;`?

Comment: Yes I did, and I got the same strange behaviour.

Comment: Do you get any warnings on the compile? Maybe there's some library code that defines `pwm` and you're shadowing it strangely?

Comment: This is the problem with global variables. Since `pwm` can be modified anywhere else in your code the problem can also be caused anywhere else in your code. I would start by looking at every line that references `pwm` and make sure it's doing what you think it should be.

Comment: I don't get any compile error. I also renamed it to pwm1, so I could be sure, that it is not affected by some internal Arduino variable, but with now effect. Also there is no other occurence of the variable with the same name in my code.

Comment: Can you post your entire sketch? There must be something missing.

Comment: I tried it on an actual Arduino, substituting "result = flc->cog(errV, errDtV);" with "result = 31.98;". I got the expected result, 31.98, 63.96, 95.94, 127.92, 159.90, 191.88, 223.86, etc.

Comment: I posted the entire sketch to the original question. I will try to rename the `result` variable and will see if it helps.

Comment: Ok, so renaming it won't help.

Comment: Now I tried hardcode the result value insted of computing it with `cog()` function and it works. So I guess the problem is in FLC class. I added the source code of it to the question post.

Comment: try to declare it as static in the loop function. Maybe you have code in interrupts that is modifying your memory...

Comment: I think that I excluded that posibility by hardcoding the value. I think that the problem will be in the FLC class, but I really don't know where.

Comment: Think in terms of one of the rules[] writing to the wrong memory location.  Start debugging by adding println(pwm1) before and after the call to cog().  Second, change the variable name to 'apwm' which will change the sort order and move the variable in the memory map (key is to change the first letter).

Answer (score 1):

Something in your function cog() is stomping on the variable pwm.  Once the float variable is corrupt, Serial.print() will just show zero.  The sample below shows that with the float set to 0xffffff, the floating point math library stops making any operation on the variable.

Run the sample program below and you will see that one time pwm prints correctly.  After the first bad call, it prints zeros.  Also the memory occupied no longer changes.

```
pwm=0.50 zpwm=0.50
pwm=0.00 zpwm=3.95 result=3.45
255-255-255-255
pwm=0.00 zpwm=4.45
pwm=0.00 zpwm=7.90 result=3.45
255-255-255-255
```

Sample program showing a function that writes to wrong memory location.
Looking at the memory map output by the linker, the variables are placed in memory in the order listed.  So writing past the end of var, will corrupt pwm.

```
float zpwm = 0;
byte var = 0;
float pwm = 0;
float result = 0;


float badactor() {
  *((long*)(&var+1)) = -1;
  return 3.45;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {

  zpwm += 0.5;
  pwm += 0.5;

  Serial.print("pwm=");
  Serial.print(pwm);
  Serial.print(" zpwm=");
  Serial.println(zpwm);

  result = badactor();
  pwm += result;
  zpwm += result;

  Serial.print("pwm=");
  Serial.print(pwm);
  Serial.print(" zpwm=");
  Serial.print(zpwm);
  Serial.print(" result=");
  Serial.println(result);

  uint8_t* ptr;
  ptr = (uint8_t*)&pwm;
  Serial.print((int)*(ptr));
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.print((int)*(ptr+1));
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.print((int)*(ptr+2));
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.println((int)*(ptr+3));

  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I have added print statements befere `cog()` and after it and also after the addition and if I run it, after some time I get this:

    `BEFORE COG: 90.72`

 `RESULT: 1.35`
 `AFTER COG: 90.72`
 `AFTER ADDITION: 92.07`

 `BEFORE COG: 92.07`
 `RESULT: 0.00`
 `AFTER COG: 92.07`
 `AFTER ADDITION: 0.00`

It seams that the corruption of the apwm variable is done by the addition. But I totally don't understand why?!

Comment: Check for divide by zero.  If denominator is zero, then the result is not a number.  That value will cause every operation involved to also return NaN.